# Second order ODE oscillator (pendulum).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Pretty much a pendulum with variyng length based on the angle.

$\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta}(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2+\lambda *\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+9.8\lambda*\sin\theta=0$

$\lambda(\theta)=a^2+b^2-2ab\sin\theta$

$l=\sqrt\lambda$ (you can make that substitution later if possible).

Conditions:

$a$ and $b$ are constants.

$\sin\theta\approx\theta$ (you can just replace sin with just theta if you want)

$\theta(t):\theta(0)=\theta_0$

${\dot{\theta}}(0)=0$

I really don't have the experience to solve this. If someone could show the answer and some steps along the way that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

We have

$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta}\dot\theta = -2ab\cos\theta\dot\theta
$$

then

$$
\frac{d\lambda}{d\theta} = -2ab\cos\theta
$$

following the pertinent substitutions.